# setTimeLimit persists after function completes

Tags: r

Using a simple test function

```
timefoo<-function(x,trans=TRUE){
setTimeLimit(elapse=4, transient=trans)
warning('starting...')
Sys.sleep(x)
warning('woke up')
return(x)
}
```

The function terminates properly when  I call, say, `timefoo(5)` , but:

```
 timefoo(3)
[1] 3
Warning messages:
1: In timefoo(3) : starting...
2: In timefoo(3) : woke up
Error: reached elapsed time limit
```

Can someone explain what exactly is happening?  It's as though `setTimeLimit` keeps running after `timefoo` has finished and exited.  Setting `transient=FALSE` is worse, as it then sets the timeout for my console commands and gives me the error message after every command (plus 4 seconds).

Edit: in response to Gavin's questions, here's a sequence of two calls

```
Rgames> timefoo(5)
Error in Sys.sleep(x) : reached elapsed time limit
In addition: Warning message:
In timefoo(5) : starting...
Rgames> timefoo(3)
[1] 3
Warning messages:
1: In timefoo(3) : starting...
2: In timefoo(3) : woke up
Error: reached elapsed time limit
```

I manually waited 10 sec between commands, so there's no doubt the final error message is due to the `timefoo(3)` call.  Are there any R_ENVIRON variables that I may have fouled up that are causing this behavior?  I've only tested this so far on Windows7, R64.

Comment: `timefoo(3)` works for me without error.

Comment: I wonder if the second error came from running `timefoo(5)` earlier? I got `Error in as.name(name) : reached elapsed time limit` and then `Warning message: In .completeToken() : restarting interrupted promise evaluation` randomly some time after `timefoo(3)`. Retrying `timefoo(3)` hasn't produced any similar things second time round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same error message (running R-2.16 devel under Win 7).

The help page `?setTimeLimit` states:

> ‘setTimeLimit’ sets limits which apply to each top-level computation,
>   that is a command line (including any continuation lines) entered at 
>   the console or from a file.

So it isn't really designed to be run from inside a function.  If you want to do that, then try this alternative:

```
timed_computation <- function(expr, time_limit = 1)
{
  setTimeLimit(elapsed = time_limit, transient = TRUE)
  ans <- expr
  setTimeLimit(elapsed = Inf, transient = TRUE)
  ans
}

timed_computation(1 + 1)            #should return 2
timed_computation(Sys.sleep(2))     #should throw an error
```

Comment: Yep, that solves the problem.  The "real" answer, I suspect, is that I shouldn't be using `setTimeLimit` as a way to force a timeout when a function runs long.  'Specially now that `evalWithTimeout` is in the `utils` package.